# matching first two letters of the first two words

Tags: php, regex

I'm using regex + php
I would match the first two letters of the first two word of a line

For example for the line :

```
Mr Christophe Mailler Jean Dupon
```

I need to match :

```
Ch Ma
```

I tried this regex :

```
(?:Mr|Mme)\s+\b([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z])
```

But it matches only Ch

Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extend the pattern match the second word, too, like this:

```
(?:Mr|Mme)\s+([a-zA-Z]{2})\S*\s+([a-zA-Z]{2})
```

I'd also recommend taking advantage of [Unicode support](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) in the PCRE engine using a pattern like this:

```
(?:Mr|Mme)\s+(\pL{2})\S*\s+(\pL{2})
```

For example:

```
$input = "Mr Christophe Mailler Jean Dupon";
preg_match("/(?:Mr|Mme)\s+(\pL{2})\S*\s+(\pL{2})/iu", $input, $output);
echo $output[1] . ' ' . $output[2]; // Ch Ma
```

Comment: Worked like a charm ! Thank you very much p.s.w.g